# Elysia cron Execution time vs Shutdown time

Tags: 7, cron

While looking to the Cron Status Tab, I can see this information above every cron channel :

```
Last run: 14/06/2013 - 02:00
Last execution time: 597s (Shutdown: 597s) (Avg total: 307.16s, Max total: 834s)
Execution count: 137
```

What does the `Shutdown` seconds stands for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation surrounding that variable is pretty much non-existent. This is how it's calculated, in `elysia_cron_completed()`:

```
time() - $cron_completed_time
```

Where `$cron_completed_time` is a global, presumably a timestamp indicating exactly when an associated cron job ended.

I'm afraid you'll need to infer exactly what that timestamp is from the above; I *think* it refers to the gap between when a cron job was completed, and the time it was logged in the database.